# Weird problem involving Jacobians

Tags: calculus

Show that $(\displaystyle\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial (x,y)})(\displaystyle\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial (r,s)})$=$(\displaystyle\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial (r,s)})$, and thus prove that $\displaystyle\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial (x,y)}$
=$1/\displaystyle\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}$

---

Essentially i solved the first part of the problem assuming that $u=f(x(r,s),y(r,s))$ and $v=g(x(r,s),y(r,s))$ and then proving by matrix multiplication that the two sides were equal. However, i'm not sure on how to proceed on the second part (i get completely different results by matrix multiplication). Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we assume that $x=f(u,v),~~y=g(u,v)$ such that $u=h(r,s),~~v=t(r,s)$. So we have:

> \begin{align}\dfrac{\partial\left(x,y\right)}{\partial\left(r,s\right)}=\left|\begin{matrix}\color{darkblue}{x_r} &x_s\\y_r&y_s\end{matrix}\right|&=\left|\begin{matrix}x_u\color{darkblue}{u_r}+x_vv_r&x_uu_s+x_vu_s\\y_uu_r+y_uu_r&y_uu_s+y_uu_s\end{matrix}\right|\\\,\\\,\\
> &=\left|\begin{matrix}x_u&x_v\\y_u&y_v\end{matrix}\right|\times\left|\begin{matrix}u_r&u_s\\v_r&v_s\end{matrix}\right|=\dfrac{\partial\left(x,y\right)}{\partial\left(u,v\right)}\times\dfrac{\partial\left(u,v\right)}{\partial\left(r,s\right)}
> \end{align}

Comment: Such nice and neat writing, with the tip of the pencil creating an artistic photo! The workings of a mathem-art-ician! +1

Comment: @amWhy: I apologize the OP not to write what I was thinking about the solution by Latex. I hope, I have not break the Community's privacy here. Thanks.

Comment: What do you see as the problem? I think your image is just fine, and can't see how you may have broken any privacy policies!

Comment: Nice solution! How do we know that we can make that assumption though? Is it a definition of the jacobian or you just need to assume it?

Comment: @B.S. Please check if I didn't change the meaning by LaTeXifying the image. Also I don't know what you mean by the arrow. (If it is pointing to $x_uu_r$ or to $u_r$ only or to the entire $x_uu_r+x_vv_r$)